# Mapbox.js GEOJson with Markercluster

Tags: javascript, leaflet, mapbox

I would like to implement GEOJson with MarkerCluster with mapbox.js.

Without Markercluster, everything works fine:

```
  $.ajax({
        url: 'dashboard/geoJSON',
        dataType: 'json',
        type: 'POST',
        success: function(geojson) {

            locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map)
            locations.on('layeradd', function (e) {
                var marker = e.layer;
                markers.push(marker);
            });

            locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);

            ...
```

But when ill try to implement MarkerCluster, it only shows 1 marker

```
        ...
        success: function(geojson) {

            locations = L.mapbox.featureLayer().addTo(map)
            var clusterGroup = new L.MarkerClusterGroup();
            locations.on('layeradd', function (e) {
                var marker = e.layer;
                markers.push(marker);
                clusterGroup.addLayer(markers);
            });
            locations.setGeoJSON(geojson);
            map.addLayer(clusterGroup);
```

And shows me the following error:

```
TypeError: t.onAdd is not a function
```

Can anyone help me out, how can i successfully combine markercluster with GEOJson from an remote server?
Thanks in advance

**// edit: Found an different example where it already works using:**

```
      var markers = L.markerClusterGroup();

      var geoJsonLayer = L.geoJson(geojson, {
          onEachFeature: function (feature, layer) {

          }
       });
       markers.addLayer(geoJsonLayer);

       map.addLayer(markers);    

       map.fitBounds(markers.getBounds());
```

But now it looses my "default" styling with properties like "marker-color" - "marker-size".

How can i style my markers now?

Mapbox is a little bit weird, it looks like there are always at least 10 ways to solve such things ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your `markers` variable is an array (as you use `.push()` on it), you cannot use `clusterGroup.addLayer(markers)`. You could have used `.addLayers(markers)` (with an "s" on `addLayers`).

I guess you would not like to add the entire array at each `"layeradd"` event anyway, so maybe you meant `clusterGroup.addLayer(marker)` (without the "s" on `marker`, i.e. your individual marker / feature).

By the way, you could have used the `onEachFeature` option of your `L.mapbox.featureLayer()` instead of using the event listener.

Finally, **do not** add your Feature Group as well to the map. That is the one that is adding your only marker currently. You want to let your cluster group to handle the markers adding / removal from map automatically.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i modified my question a little bit.

Comment: Do you know how can i reset a markercluster? For example: I load my markers again when a user changes a filter, and then i would like to re-init the clustergroup. Normally ill use:       markers.forEach(function(entry) {
                    map.removeLayer(entry);
                }); , but this is not working anymore. Any ideas?

Comment: I am not sure I understand what you mean… you could try `clusterGroup.clearLayers()`. If that is not what you are looking for, maybe you should open a dedicated question with more details.